# Send data by parts in node.js express

Tags: node.js, express

I was searching the web and documentation for `node.js` `express` module and it seems there is no way to send data by parts. I have a file rendered not very fast and I want to send parts of it before everything is rendered.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a method on `response` to send data by parts?
2. What does `response.end()`?
3. If there is no way to send data by parts - what is the rationale behind? I would say it looks more blocking than non-blocking if that's true. Browser can load information faster if data is given earlier.

Sample simplified code:

```
app.get(..) {
  renderFile(file, function(data) {
    response.send(data);
  });
  response.end();
)
```

This piece of code sends only the first chunk of data. I checked - data *is* given correctly and callback is called more than one time.

Of course I can append data to the one variable and then write `response.send(data);` but I don't like this approach - it is not the way it should work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `response` object is a writable stream.  Just write to it, and Express will even set up chunked encoding for you automatically.

```
response.write(chunk);
```

You can also pipe to it if whatever is creating this "file" presents itself as a readable stream.  http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: Please elaborate on the piping and give an example. I feel this would be very relevant to a lot of people, as it is actually a better solution in a lot of cases.

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard I can't give a specific example because the code in the question doesn't provide any context as to where the data is coming from.  `sourceStream.pipe(response)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

the easy way to do this is to convert the data into a readable stream and pipe it to the response object.
here is my nodejs code. hope this might help

```
var express= require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const JSONStreamStringify = require('json-stream-stringify');

var app=express();
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.post('/node_test_pipe', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    console.log("Request from:"+req.url);
    var obj={
             my:1,
             two:2
            }
    JSONStreamStringify(obj).pipe(res);
    var obj={
             my:3,
             two:4
            }
    JSONStreamStringify(obj).pipe(res);
    });

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides using `Response.write()` method to chunk send and `Response.end()` to mark the end!

If you have a stream! You can **pipe** it directly to the **Response** object! And all get handled automatically!

See the example bellow for a file readable stream:

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // The filename is simple the local directory and tacks on the requested url
  var filename = __dirname+req.url;

  // This line opens the file as a readable stream
  var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);

  // This will wait until we know the readable stream is actually valid before piping
  readStream.on('open', function () {
    // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
    readStream.pipe(res); // <====== here
  });

  // This catches any errors that happen while creating the readable stream (usually invalid names)
  readStream.on('error', function(err) {
    res.end(err);
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

You can do that with any Stream. Just pipe it to Respond object!

The example above come from here:

https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream/

## Bottom line

Use pipe! And it's nice too look and understand better!

Here the link from the doc!

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options

> The readable.pipe() method attaches a **Writable** stream to the **readable**, causing it to switch automatically into flowing mode and push all of its data to the attached Writable.

And note about chaining

> it is possible to attach multiple Writable streams to a single Readable stream.
>
> The readable.pipe() method returns a reference to the destination stream making it possible to set up chains of piped streams

example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const r = fs.createReadStream('file.txt'); // read stream
const z = zlib.createGzip(); // write stream
const w = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt.gz'); // write stream
r.pipe(z).pipe(w);
```

Read the doc for more!

Answer (score 1):

Express extends Connect which extends HTTP I believe. Looking at the [HTTP API](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html), it seems that what you are looking for is [`response.write`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback), which takes a chunk of data to send as a response body. I then believe you can use [`response.end`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) on the end signal.

Answer (score -1):

The response object can be written to. In your case, the following would be a solution:

```
renderFile(file, function(data) {
  response.send(data);
});
response.end();
```

If you have the opportunity to get the file as a stream this can be streamlined further:

```
file.getReadableStream().pipe(response);
```