# How can I make real-time list using Node.js and Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Using Firebase and Node.js I'm trying to make a real-time list, see code below:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    db.ref('contacts').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        console.log(data);
        res.render('index', { contacts: data });
    });
});
```

but is giving me this error

**Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send data by parts in node.js express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644066/send-data-by-parts-in-node-js-express)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to send multiple responses from an Express route.  The error message is telling you that's not possible.  Once you call `res.render()`, you are declaring the full response to be sent to the client, and that's all you can send.  The client will have to make another request to get an update.

If you want to keep a socket open to the client to send updates over time, you're going to need a websocket or some other way to keep the connection open.  [express-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws) is one thing to try on the backend.  Note that this will not work with Cloud Functions and probably other serverless providers.